# Best way of transforming random variable

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am working with the following code:

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = 
 TransformedDistribution[u - Log[u], 
  u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}]]
Plot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], x], {x, 1, 2}, Filling -> Axis]
```

Basically, I want to transform a uniform random variable, $u$ into $u-\log{u}$, and plot the pdf of the new random variable. However, Mathematica seems to take a long time using the function **TransformedDistribution** and moreover, I am not being able to retrieve a Plot, so perhaps the function is not working well under my transformation.

Do you have any suggestions on how to obtain a solution for this?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3625412/transforming-a-uniform-random-variable#comment7452688_3625412.

Comment: I don't understand why @m0nhawk deleted his/her correct answer.

Comment: @user64494 $U$ and $\log U$ are not independent as assumed in that answer.

Comment: @JimB: I've demonstrated how to correct it, considering two IID.

Comment: The command `PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], x]` does not work for me.

Comment: It's high time to go to bed for me, so the result of `Expand[Mean[
   TransformedDistribution[x*Log[x], 
    x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}]]] - 
  Mean[TransformedDistribution[Log[x], 
     x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}]]]*
   Mean[UniformDistribution[{1, 2}]]] ` may be useful for somebody.

Comment: Your question on the Math StackExchange site was (essentially) about $u-\log u$.  Here did you mean $u+\log u$ or $u-\log u$ ?

Comment: Hey @JimB, you're right, I meant $u-\log u$, will correct now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might just be with the `Plot` command that is giving you trouble.

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[ u - Log[u], u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}]];
pdf = PDF[dist, z] // FullSimplify
```

results in

[image: Density function]

To plot that one can use

```
Plot[Evaluate[pdf[[1, 1, 1]]], {z, 1, 2 - Log[2]}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, Automatic}}]
```

[image: Plot of density function]

As a check:

```
zz = RandomVariate[dist, 100000];
Show[Histogram[zz, 100, "PDF"],
 Plot[Evaluate[pdf[[1, 1, 1]]], {z, 1, 2 - Log[2]}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 30}}]]
```

[image: Histogram and density]

***Addition:***

The resulting `Piecewise` function from `PDF[dist, z]` has two pieces that are "identities" that are true when `1 <= z <= 2 - Log[2]` but when `Plot` evaluates the function with machine precision numbers, things go weird.  So here is a cleaned up version of the resulting probability density function that plays well with `Plot`:

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[ u - Log[u], u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}]];
pdf = PDF[dist, z] // TrigToExp // FunctionExpand;
pdf = Piecewise[{{pdf[[1, 1, 1]], 1 <= z <= 2 - Log[2]}}, 0]
```

[image: Cleaned up pdf]

```
Plot[pdf, {z, 0.9, 3/2}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], PlotRangeClipping -> None]
```

[image: Plot of pdf]

Comment: Something to adjust in view of the result of `Plot[Evaluate[pdf[[1, 1, 1]]], {z, 0, 4}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, Automatic}}]` .

Comment: Also `Plot[Evaluate[pdf], {z, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, Automatic}}]` produces an error communication and an empty plot.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks, that makes it better: I'll modify the `PlotRange` as you suggest.  On your other comment:  that happens because of the conditions of the pdf are not always true when using machine precision numbers that `Plot` uses.  I'll put in a fix for that.

Comment: Looks good, thanks! Is there a way to introduce a parameter when working with """RandomVariate?""" Say """dist[a_] = 
  TransformedDistribution[a*u - Log[u], 
   u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}]];
zz[a_] = RandomVariate[dist[a], 100000];"""? And then use """Manipulate""" over the parameter $a$?

Comment: @JinB: Let us call things by their proper names: you cannot plot `pdf` on the interval from 0 to 4.

Comment: @user64494.  I will be able to do so after an edit.

Comment: @JimB: `pdf = Piecewise[{{pdf[[1, 1, 1]], 1 <= z <= 2 - Log[2]}}, 0]` is made by hand, you are not able to deduce it from                                                           
                     `PDF[dist, z] // TrigToExp // FunctionExpand` .

Comment: @user64494 I'm sure someone could supply the steps.  And it was not just made by hand; my small brain helped a bit.

Comment: For the more general case with $a>0$ I believe from looking at the pattern of results for various values of $a$ the pdf of `a u - Log[u]` where $u\sim U(1,2)$ is `pdf[z_, a_] := 
 Piecewise[{{ProductLog[-1, -a E^-z]/(
    a (1 + ProductLog[-1, -a E^-z])), a <= z <= 2 a - Log[2]}}, 0]`.