# Plot of Piecewise function is slow

Tags: plotting, piecewise

While working on answer for question ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219592/2342)) I found out that the `Plot` is incredible slow for Piecewise function:

Some preparations:

```
\[ScriptCapitalD]1 = 
 TransformedDistribution[Log[u], 
  u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}]]
(* TransformedDistribution[
 Log[\[FormalX]], \[FormalX] \[Distributed] 
  UniformDistribution[{1, 2}]] *)

\[ScriptCapitalD] = 
 TransformedDistribution[
  u + v, {u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}], 
   v \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalD]1}]
(* TransformedDistribution[
 u + v, {u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}], 
  v \[Distributed] 
   TransformedDistribution[
    Log[\[FormalX]], \[FormalX] \[Distributed] 
     UniformDistribution[{1, 2}]]}] *)
```

This looks perfectly fine:

```
s[x_] := PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], x]    
pw[x_] := PiecewiseExpand[s[x], 1 <= x <= 2]
pw[x] // InputForm
(* Piecewise[{{1, x >= 1 + Log[2]}, {(-E + E^x)/E, Inequality[1, Less, x, Less, 
    1 + Log[2]]}}, 0] *)
```

But, the `Plot` is extremely slow and never finishes:

```
Plot[pw[x], {x, 1, 2}]
```

But, if I copy `InputForm` of `pw`, it magically started working:

```
pw2[x_] := 
 Piecewise[{{1, x >= 1 + Log[2]}, {(-E + E^x)/E, 
    Inequality[1, Less, x, Less, 1 + Log[2]]}}, 0]

Plot[pw2[x], {x, 1, 2}]
(* produces plot *)
```

---

Using *Mathematica* 12.1.

Comment: If you had done `pw[x_] = PiecewiseExpand[s[x], 1 <= x <= 2]` (i.e. use `Set[]` instead of `SetDelayed[]`), you would not have encountered this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 Plot[Evaluate@pw[x], {x, 1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ok, it works. But why? I can't see `Piecewise` having any `Hold`.

Comment: @m0nhawk  plot has Hold property. `Plot has attribute HoldAll and evaluates f only after assigning specific numerical values to x.`